# All main Terminal commands

Tags: command-line

What should I write in Terminal to see all main commands?

Comment: What do you consider to be "main commands"? And just the executables or also "main commands" including "main options". In my opinion this is *too broad* as it currently stands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the most direct answer to your question is:

```
compgen -b
```

which lists all built-in commands

```
compgen -c
```

lists all commands (maybe better to use `compgen -c | more` since it's a long list)

A nice list of core commands can be found [here](http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/basic-unix.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it's the correct way or not but in my opinion you can try the following trick as you want the list of commands through terminal

To see the available commands in Ubuntu you can go to the following directories and get a listing of them

**WARNING**

**DO NOT TRY TO EDIT OR ANYTHING IN THOSE DIRECTORIES**

```
cd /usr/bin/
ls
```

and

```
cd /usr/sbin/
ls
```

By using the above commands you can see the list of commands then to get to know more about those commands use

```
man {command-name}
```

Or try online resources which lists the commands so that you don't screw up anything on your system

> [Linux Commands](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1617273)

Also see the link below:

> [List commands in Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/compgen-linux-command/)

Answer (score 0):

A compilation of all commands used in linux is given here

> [ss64](http://ss64.com/bash/)

they even linked the man pages, so it is a great resource to check out!