# Complete List of Terminal Commands and all their parameters

Tags: 14.04, command-line, books

I was wondering if there was any complete guide to the Linux Terminal (don't mind buying a book or something), specifically, I want the list (or book) to do an A-Z of the commands with all their parameters, reasons why you'd use those commands and examples.

If anyone has recommendations I'd be most appreciative!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd point you to http://ss64.com normally, but their server is down tight now.

Comment: I'll add it to bookmarks and check back each day :-)

Comment: How about searching an online book retailer like http://amazon.com? Search for "linux command line" sans quote. Also see http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php

Comment: @user68186 because one book is always going to be more detailed then the next, I was hoping to find a recommended book that covers all bases instead of buying one, then finding there's a better one for the same price

Comment: The buyers at Amazon rated this one highly. I have no personal knowledge. I just use the man command and the Google search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list complete list of Terminal Commands use:

```
compgen -b
```

which lists all built-in commands

```
compgen -c
```

lists all commands (maybe better to use `compgen -c | less` since it's a long list)

Taken from [All main Terminal commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/337878/283843) answered by [@Cubiq](https://askubuntu.com/users/63332/cubiq)

---

And below commands are what you want for complete details and their parameters:

```
man <command>
info <command>
<command> -h
<command> --help
```

If you want more information, type:

```
info coreutils <command>
```

Comment: I know you can do that but a book that has examples and what situations you'd use them is a lot clearer for me.

Comment: @TreyTaylor That manual pages is what writes in books :) You can use a for-loop to list all of them and make it a PDF format book for yourself. (if you don't like my answer, I'll delete it or I can keep it for someone else :) even from `info coreutils <command>` command you will see a lot of examples